# How can I declare a templated class type as a member method, *not* a property?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a class that is expected to implement a single method in a given interface (with a different name).

For the most part, this works via TypeScript generics (see `RpcHandler` below).

However, because TypeScript makes a distinction between member methods and member properties, I get compile errors when implementing the function as a method, rather than as a property.

---

Is there a way to hint to typescript that `RpcHandler#execute` should be a method, and not a property?

```js
class Thing { }

interface RpcActions {
  getThing(id: string): Promise<Thing>
}

// ---

class RpcHandler<ActionName extends keyof RpcActions> {
  execute: RpcActions[ActionName];
}

// ---

class GetThingAsMethodHandler extends RpcHandler<'getThing'> {
  // How can I declare the type of execute so that it is a member
  // and not a property, so this doesn't error?

  // Error: Class 'RpcHandler<"makeThing">' defines instance member
  // property 'execute', but extended class 'MakeThingHandler' defines
  // it as instance member function.
  async execute(data: Object): Promise<Thing> {
    return new Thing();
  }
}

// Workaround, for now

class GetThingAsPropertyHandler extends RpcHandler<'getThing'> {
  execute = async (id: string): Promise<Thing> => {
    return new Thing();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no distinction between methods and properties for interfaces. It's maintained for classes probably because methods are defined on the prototype, and properties, if they are initialized, are assigned in the constructor - so the would-be method defined in the prototype of derived class will have no effect over own property assigned in the constructor of the base class.

So, if you can turn `RpcHandler` into an interface, it almost works, except that `execute` in `MakeThingHandler` can't take any arguments:

```
class Thing { }

interface RpcActions {
  makeThing(): Promise<Thing>
  getThing(id: string): Promise<Thing>
}

// ---

interface RpcHandler<ActionName extends keyof RpcActions> {
  execute: RpcActions[ActionName];
}


// ---

class MakeThingHandler implements RpcHandler<'makeThing'> {

  async execute(): Promise<Thing> {
    return new Thing();
  }
}
```

With your code, when `execute` has `data: Object` argument, you will get

```
test.ts(17,7): error TS2420: Class 'MakeThingHandler' incorrectly implements interface 'RpcHandler<"makeThing">'.
  Types of property 'execute' are incompatible.
    Type '(data: number) => Promise<Thing>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<Thing>'.
```

Possible workaround for that is to declare makeThing() in RpcActions as

```
makeThing(arg: any): Promise<Thing>
```

Comment: Ah! That last error you see is because you want 'getThing' as the template type (not 'makeThing').  I've cleaned up the example a bit - but interfaces are what I'm looking for, thanks!